# python while loop unexpected behavior

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm relatively new to Python, and I don't understand the following code produces the subsequently unexpected output:

```
x = input("6 divided by 2 is")
while x != 3:
    print("Incorrect. Please try again.")
    x = input("6 divided by 2 is")
    print(x)
```

the output of which is:

```
6 divided by 2 is 3
Incorrect. Please try again.
6 divided by 2 is 3
3
Incorrect. Please try again.
6 divided by 2 is
```

Why is the while loop still being executed even though x is equal to 3?

Answer (score 3):

`input()` returns a string, which you are comparing to an integer. This will always return false.
You'll have to wrap `input()` in a call to `int()` for a valid comparison.

```
x = int(input("6 divided by 2 is"))
while x != 3:
    print("Incorrect. Please try again.")
    x = int(input("6 divided by 2 is"))
    print(x)
```

Read more on `int()` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error is because you are not parsing the input like so:

```
x = int(input("6 divided by 2 is"))
```

If you replace your inputer statement with that, it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

input method gives the string. So you need to typecast to int as:

```
x = int(input("6 divided by 2 is"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer to your question

```
Guesses = 0
while(Guesses < 101):
    try:
        x = int(input("6 divided by 2 is: "))
        if(x == 3):
            print("Correct! 6 divide by 2 is", x)
            break
        else:
            print("Incorrect. try again")
            Guesses += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a number. Try again.")
        Guesses += 1
else:
    print("Out of guesses.")
```

I am assuming you wanted the user to `input` a `number` so i put your code into a `while\else loop` containing a `try\except loop`. The `try\except` loop ensures that if the users `inputs` a number, a `ValueError` will appear and it will inform them that what they `inputted was not a number`. The `while\else loop` ensures that the user will be inputted the question if the `Guesses` limit is no higher than `100`. This code will ensure that if the user `guesses the answer` which is `3`, the user will be prompted that `they got the answer right and the loop will end`; if the users guesses anything besides 3 (Number wise) the `answer will be incorrect` and the user `will be prompted the question again`;  if the `user guesses a string` it will be classified as a ValueError and they will be notified that `their answer wasn't a number and that the user has to try again`.

Considering this was asked a long time ago, I'm assuming your probably forgot about this or you figured out the answer but if not try this and tell me if you like this answer. Thank :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried this myself now with python 2.6, and did get an int without converting to int. For example, when I try the following:

```
x = input("6 divided by 2 is")
print "Your input is %s, %s" % (x, type(x))
```

I get the following:

```
6 divided by 2 is 2
Your input is 2, <type 'int'>
```

So is this a version issue? Or maybe an environment issue (I'm using OS X)?
What I do conclude is that it should be a good practice using previous recommendations using int().

Comment: `input` in Python 2 evaluates the input automatically, which is one reason why you should always use `raw_input`. In Python 3 `input` acts like Py2's `raw_input`.